# Why set a bufferSize in the FileStream ctor, if we set it later when reading?

Tags: c#, .net

The docs for [FileStream Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f20d7x6t(v=vs.110).aspx)  don't mention a reason. It just says:

> bufferSize
>
> Type: System.Int32
>
> A positive Int32 value greater than 0 indicating the buffer size. The default buffer size is 4096.

But later we use methods such as [Read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read(v=vs.110).aspx)   in which we specify the buffer size and supply the buffer itself.

So why specify a buffer size in the constructor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are different buffers. One is internal buffer of `FileStream` itself (size of that you pass to constructor), and another one is caller's buffer (that one from `Read`). They are not related.

Say you pass 4000 to constructor as internal buffer size and then call:

```
Read(buffer, 0, 100);
```

What will happen (in simplified terms, and assuming that is first read from this stream) is `FileStream` will go and read 4000 bytes from file and store it in it's internal buffer. Then it will write 100 bytes to caller's buffer.

If you do

```
Read(buffer, 0, 8000)
```

It will go and read 4000 from file to the internal buffer, write 4000 to caller's buffer then will go again and read next 4000 from file to internal buffer, then complete writing to caller's one.

Why have that internal buffer? Because it's expensive to bother file system for every small read. Say you read `FileStream` byte by byte, 4000 times. It will bother filesystem only once, the rest 3999 it will return from internal buffer.

Comment: Thanks. +1. So what would happen if the read buffer is larger than the ctor one?

Comment: as an impementation detail, the internal buffer could also be handled by the OS, with the size simply passed down when opening the file handle

Comment: @MarcGravell I don't understand your comment. Are you saying that the ctor's bufferSize might be ignored?

Comment: @ispiro updated answer. This is of course high level description, to help undestanding. As for Marc comment - he means (I think) that FileStream might not have real buffer itself (that is `byte[]`) but instead OS will handle this. But size is not ignored - it is passed down to OS when you start reading the file and OS will use this size for it's buffer. So you ask FileStream for 100 bytes - it asks OS for 100 bytes - OS reads 4000 internally but returns just 100 and so on.

Comment: @ispiro no, I mean it might not relate to the `FileStream` code, but to a lower level - same result, different impementation

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks for clarifying that!